# Want to secure jwt in react based app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jwt

I have searched and read many articles where to store `JWT` whether in `session` or in `cookie` but i am unable to know that what is correct place or way to store my `JWT` in my `react redux` app

I am storing `JWT` in session-storage,but it is easily getting exposed from developer tool.And if i try with `HTTPonly` `cookie` then that cant be read by `javascript`.So i am worried where to store JWT token which cant be exposed to user or what should be the step or measures to make the application secured so user doesn't know about jwt token

Please provide suggestion

Comment: `And if i try with HTTPonly cookie then that cant be read by javascript.` Why do you want to access cookie with javascript?

Comment: it can be userid or something else

Comment: Make a connection to your auth server and fetch user profile. Store it as you wish.

Comment: Define your security requirements please. JWT itself is encrypted and cannot be decoded on the client. So long as you are keeping it in the client, it will _always_ be exposed through developer tools, won't matter if its cookie, local storage etc.

Comment: Ok,my concern is that jwt shouldnt be exposed to user by anyways,i have gone through many web app which use jwt but i never seen any JWT stored in local,session storage which i can access,I dont know how they store whether they decrpyt it on front end and store or something other,please help how would be the standard approach with jwt

Comment: @hazardous : only JWEs are encrypted, the ususal signed JWT (JWS) is just Base64Url encoded and can of course be decoded on the client. Please don't confuse encoding/decoding with encrypting/decrypting. These are very different things

Comment: @jps thanks for the correction. I was a wrong to presume that the payload is encrypted. Jwt is merely signed, not necessarily encrypted.

Comment: @tapandave you can only prevent script attacks by using http-only cookies. I don't think Dev tools exposure is a threat vector, unless the attacker has physical access.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help:

Use a `httpOnly` `secure` cookie.

Cookies are sent to the server automatically when you make a request to the server, though only the relevant cookies are sent (thankfully).

You should do authentication server side, and not worry about passing a `JWT` cookie in an individual request from your client side JS. This is the only good way to mitigate a XSS attack that I know of

Answer (score 0):

You should store token in `local storage`, `session storage`, and i don't think you can hide any client-side information from users.